# How can I pass name in url after redirect to thank you page in contact form7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I created a contact form 7 and after submission it is also redirecting us to thank you page but i also want a url parameter where filled name also pass on url with thank you page link. I checked on google but not found any relevant answer.
I am sharing the code below that i have done to redirect it-

//redirect to thank you page after submission

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
  
function mycustom_wp_footer()
 { 

?>
<script>

   document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event )
 
    {  
        location = 'https://www.brainiuminfotech.com/thank-you/';

    }, false );

</script>
<?php

}
```

Comment: Check this article https://vincoding.com/passing-contact-form-7-data-thank-page/, it will give you an idea of how you can pass the data in thankyou page.

Comment: No i think you unable to get my question, question is how to pass name in url like this- /thank-you/?name=aman

Comment: I got your question and that article has answers, You need to read it carefully, specially the **Contact Form 7 ‘Additional Settings’ Tab** section, Jquery code is available there that will help you do the thing you are looking for.